# How to insert a character when editing a file using ISPF Edit via TN3270?

Tags: mainframe, zos, mvs, ispf, 3270

The editor in mvs3.8 TK4- is very different from the editors that I have used in Windows and Linux. I am trying to figure out how to insert a character between two characters in the editor. For example:

```
//HERC01C JOB (COBOL),
```

If i want to insert an O after C to  `//HERC01CO JOB (COBOL),` the only ways i can do are by backspacing from the end of the line upto C and type everything after that again; or by moving all the characters to a position to the right using `)1` command and the typing over everything form the beginning till C. Is there a way to add O here after C so that it will insert O and automatically move all the characters after that one place to the right?

Comment: I am using Hercules emulator and using a 3270 terminal emulator to connect to it.

Comment: Not an answer but the ISPF editor is very powerful. Anything you can edit can be scripted and there are a large number of primary and line commands for filtering and moving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming you are using the **ISPF editor**

- enter `nulls on` in the command line. This will convert trailing spaces to nulls
- if the line is full, you will need to split it
- position cursor where you want to enter the new character
- Make sure you are in insert mode the insert key swaps between insert and over-write modes.
- Type the character.

Comment: To add to what Bruce wrote: Whether or not you are in insert mode is usually indicated by a caret ```^``` in the operator information line (the bottom most line) in the editor. Also, 3270 emulators usually have a setting to either stay in insert mode upon pressing ```ENTER``` (more precisely, pressing an action key), or to revert to overwrite mode.

Comment: Using 'nulls on' and then using Insert to toggle b/w insert and overwrite modes did the trick. Thanks guys.

Comment: You can also place the cursor at the end of the text and use the `EOF` keyboard function.   Also, TK4 is a distribution of MVS so your question is more generally about using 3270 I think than TK4 as the same question applies to z/OS systems today.

Comment: How different is the modern 64 bit z/OS user interface from the mvs3.8 interface?

Comment: Editing interfaces range from ISPF (old school) to VScode with Zowe extensions.   Depends on what your editing and the experience you want